# Django Type Error adding data to model via django admin backend

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have no clue what happened... Yesterday I was in django/admin page testing out the form, making sure I can upload images and it was working perfectly fine. This morning, I get a type error and I cannot for the life of me track down where it's coming from.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class MenuCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, default='')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=120, unique=False, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menu Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return '' + self.name


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', width_field=200, height_field=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=240, unique=False, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menu Items'

    def __str__(self):
        return '' + self.title
```

And my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from menu.models import MenuItem, MenuCategory

# Register your models here
admin.site.register(MenuItem)
admin.site.register(MenuCategory)


class MenuInlines(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MenuItem


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MenuInlines]
```

I really don't understand where the TypeError is =(

This seemed to be working fine yesterday and I have no clue what I changed.

I did 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' just to be sure... Any clue? Did I leave something out that might be pertinent?

Comment: Could you show us the exact type error that you had?

Comment: What type of error you got ? Can you upload it ? Where is the error ( In cmd ) or ( In html ) ?

Comment: Yes, it was getattr(): attribute name must be string.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/menu/menuitem/add/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
getattr(): attribute name must be string

Comment: You can also set the size of the image in html also. So you should try that in html.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what it was! Wow! So strange since I had this working yesterday, but thank you so much! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like in HTML :-

```
{% load daguerre %}
<img src="{% adjust model.image 'fill' width=128 height=256 %}" />
```